# Is it possible to author a custom Azure DevOps task in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, task, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server

We use Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on-prem).

I would like to author a custom Azure DevOps task in Powershell. The examples I have seen so far on the web are about authoring it in Typescript.

I wonder - is it the only way? Can we use Powershell, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use PowerShell in your custom build task.

You need to edit this section in `task.json`:

```
  "execution": {
    "PowerShell3": {
      "target": "ps-script.ps1",
      "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)"
    }
  }
```

And you need to install the `VstsTaskSdk` Powershell Module:

- open up Powershell
- navigate to the `root/buildtask` of directory of your extension
- execute `mkdir ps_modules` and then navigate into the new directory
- your `pwd` should read `root/buildtask/ps_modules`
- execute `Save-Module -Name VstsTaskSdk -Path .` which will save the module to disk.
- Flatten the directory structure by removing the version number. For example you will have a path of `root/buildtask/ps_modules/VstsTaskSdk/0.10.0/*` which should now read `root/buildtask/ps_modules/VstsTaskSdk/*`

A full tutorial exist [here](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/dev-ops-vsts-custom-build-task-extension).

You can also see an example for custom task with PS on [this](https://github.com/shayki5/azure-devops-create-pr-task) GitHub repo.

**Note: it works only in windows machines.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the PS script directly in your custom task. You can configure `task.json` in this way:

```
"execution": {
    "PowerShell3": {
        "target": "script.ps1",
         "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)"
    }
 }
```